# How to change the default isolation level of a transaction in a stored procedure in PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transaction, plpgsql, isolation-level

I am interested in controlling the [isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) of a transaction inside a PostgreSQL procedure but haven't found any information on how to do it. The documentation on [Transaction Management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-transactions.html) within [Chapter 42. PL/pgSQL — SQL Procedural Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql.html) only states that:

> A new transaction starts out with default transaction characteristics such as transaction isolation level.

Can we change the default isolation level? Can you provide example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be simple:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE myproc
   SET default_transaction_isolation = 'repeatable read';
```

The downside to that is that because of the limitations of transaction management inside procedures, you can no longer `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` inside such a procedure.

If you need that, you could start the procedure body like this:

```
COMMIT;  -- otherwise you get a silly error
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Transaction management inside procedures is pretty limited at the moment.